# webmessage link post back to mvc-project without sending the user back

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webmail project in mvc4. In the mail there is 3 pictures and i want the user to press one of the pictures. My problem is that the only way ive solved it for now is to send the user pack to a page where thers realy nothing on just so that i can get the information on whitch picture the user pressed. So my question is if there is any way that i can get the information from my img-link to send the information to my mvc-project whitout sending the user to another page?

```
private MailMessage WebMail(string userMail, Guid id, string name, string lastname, string custfname, string custlname)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        //TODO lägg i web config
        mail.From = new MailAddress("somemail", "mailmail");  // Lägg till specifik presis mail! 
        mail.To.Add(userMail);
        mail.Subject = string.Format("Utvärdering");
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string answer1 = "1";
        string answer2 = "2";
        string answer3 = "3";
        string answer4 = "4";
        var url1 = Url.Action("MailInput", "Home", null, "http");
        string Body = String.Format("<div class'content' style='background-color: white;'><div class='mailbody'><h1  style='color: black;'><b>Hej {9} {10}, din åsikt är det viktigaste vi vet!</b></h1><br><p style='font-size: 18px; color: black;'>Du pratade nyligen med {7} {8} på Presis i Lund AB. Vi ber dig ödmjukast att klicka på någon av bilderna nedan för att beskriva hur du upplevde kontakten. Ditt svar betyder verkligen mycket för oss.</p><br><br><a href=\'{0}?id={1}&usermail={2}&answer={3}' title='Jag fick kanonbra hjälp av er och ett underbart bemötande. Dagen är räddad!'/><img src='cid:Happy'/ alt='HTML tutorial' style='margin-right: 20px; max-height:160px; min-height:160px; width:160px; border-style: none;'></a><a href=\'{0}?id={1}&usermail={2}&answer={4}' title='Jag fick inte direkt hjälp med mitt ärende men dock ett trevligt bemötande, vet var jag skall vända mig och jag känner mig glad.'/><img src='cid:Orange'/ alt='HTML tutorial' style='border-style: none; width:160px; max-height:160px; min-height:160px; margin-right:20px;'></a><a href=\'{0}?id={1}&usermail={2}&answer={5}' title='Jag fick inte alls hjälp med mitt ärende och är arg på er.'/><img src='cid:Mad'/ alt='HTML tutorial' style='width:160; max-height:160px; min-height:160px; border-style: none;'></a><p style='font-size: 18px; color: black;'>Ditt svar använder vi i vår ständiga förbättringsprocess i att erbjuda världens bästa kundkontakt och service. Har du några konkreta förslag eller synpunkter på vad vi kan göra bättre eller vill lämna en ros så maila oss gärna på följande address: gladakunder@presis.se</p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Nej, tack! Jag vill inte få denna typ av mail igen<a href=\'{0}?id={1}&usermail={2}&answer={6}'/><button width='10' height='10'>Tryck</button></a></div></div>", url1, id, userMail, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, name, lastname, custfname, custlname);

        mail.Body = Body;
        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Body, null, "text/html");

        var path1 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/img/SUPERGLAD.png");
        LinkedResource imagelink1 = new LinkedResource(path1, "image/png");
        imagelink1.ContentId = "Happy";
        imagelink1.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink1);

        var path2 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/img/SEMIGLAD.png");
        LinkedResource imagelink2 = new LinkedResource(path2, "image/png");
        imagelink2.ContentId = "Orange";
        imagelink2.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink2);

        var path3 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/img/ARG.png");
        LinkedResource imagelink3 = new LinkedResource(path3, "image/png");
        imagelink3.ContentId = "Mad";
        imagelink3.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink3);

        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        return mail;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite figure out what your code has to do with your question and it isn't ultimately clear to me what you want to achieve at all, but *"send the information to my mvc-project whitout sending the user to another page"* sounds like you need AJAX.

Take a look at `@Ajax.BeginForm()` and `@Ajax.ActionLink()`.

Comment: I have sent the mail to the user with the code above. In the mail that the user opens is 3 imagelinks. One happy smiley, one sad smiley and one angry smiley. The user chooses one of the pictures and i want to get the information about whitch one of the pictures the user pressed.As for now i do it by sending the user to a view where there is nothing and then i get the querystring info from the user to get the info on whitch picture the user pressed. But i don't want the user to be sent to my page with nothing on. I just want the user to stay in the mail inbox while i get the info to my project

Comment: Fortunately you cannot do that from an email. They click a link, their computer opens the link in the browser. You could try to close the window using JavaScript.